# Euclids algorithm for all integer polynomials

Tags: polynomials, euclidean-algorithm

I am going through a proof of a question that asks:

Prove $\langle$x+1,x$^2$+1$\rangle$ is a maximal ideal in $\Bbb Z$[X]

The proof shows that this ideal is equal to $\langle$x+1,2$\rangle$ and then uses the following;

"Every polynomial f(x)$\in$ $\Bbb Z$ can be expressed by f(x)=(x+1)g(x) + f(-1)"

How would I go about proving this equation?

I can see this comes from Euclids Algorithm with f(x)=q(x)g(x)+r(x) with deg(r) < deg(q) = 1, so r is a constant, and I can see how this works, but am not sure how to conclude that r must be equal to f(-1)

For f a constant and when (x+1) is a factor of f this is obvious but in the final case, (non-constant, (x+1) not a factor) i am unsure how to show generally

I'm sure I'm missing something very obvious, any hints would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Cf. the [polynomial remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem)

Comment: What you describe is the Division algorithm, not the Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: The Remainder Theorem holds over any commutative ring with unity when you are dividing by a polynomial whose leading coefficient is a unit. So you can do it for $x+1$, but not for, for example, $2x+3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you know from Euclid's algorithm that
$$
f(x)=(x+1)g(x)+r
$$
where $r$ is a constant, you just plug in $x=-1$ and you find that $f(-1)=r$. This is called "the Remainder's Theorem".

Comment: Thanks so much! I knew it was something obvious, I'm kicking myself now.